# How to catch exception without the explicit use of try and catch block

Tags: c#

How to catch exceptions but without try catch block in c#?
There is a situation while automating UI, system should throw exception for certain elements if it is not available.

Comment: Are you asking how to throw an exception or how to catch one?

Answer (score 2):

there is a difference between catch and throw.  If the system needs to throw an exception, you just put "Throw new Exception()" at the appropriate line.

Catching an exception means you are doing something with it - and sometimes rethrowing it after logging.

EDIT:
based on your brief question - also consider whether exceptions are the right answer.  Sounds more like you need to validate and then give a message to the user.  Exceptions should be used on an "exceptional" basis - they are weighty and interrupt normal program flow and should be there to handle things that can't be managed in a normal validation process and often that are unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an exception, just add

```
throw new Exception();
```

wherever you want the exception to be thrown.

You can replace `Exception` with a more appropriate exception type if you want.